# Wechat Mini Porgram Push Notification

Tags: wechat, wechat-auth

Hi Recently I came to know about wechat mini program but as material is very less so I am unable to differentiate the official account and mini program.

I came to know that wechat mini doesnt have push notification but client wants to send the push notification from mini program.

The requirement is that mini program URL will be configured in official menu URL so when User will click to the link wechat will redirect to mini porgram when user clicks on any action then an API call should happen back to the offical program and send the push notification using union ID. Is my assumption right and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If by "push notification", you mean sending template message to WeChat users. WeChat's mini-program does offer an API for that.

[Here's an article on how to do it](https://medium.com/china-software-development/how-to-send-template-message-for-wechat-mini-program-856dbc4af7cc)

And the other solution as you mentioned, using unionID to get user's official account openID to send a message would also work, but the process is way more complicated. Because currently, WeChat doesn't have a simple API that let you retrieve user's openID with unionID. Meaning you will have to store the relationship of unionID and openID by yourself.

Hope this helps. :D

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you please let me know how to send the push notification using Union ID in wechat? or get the openId using Union Id

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe need the customer service message function,here is the article from the official sites:
[customer service message](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/framework/open-ability/customer-message/customer-message.html)